# Countable field which is elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

Is it possible to describe concretely a countable field which is elementary equivalent to the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers? Such a field exists by Löwenheim-Skolem.

Comment: There is a countable description. Is a concrete description a finite description?

Comment: The real algebraic numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$ of real algebraic numbers is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$.  This follows from the fact that the theory of real-closed fields is complete, and $\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$ are both real-closed fields.

Comment: It's more than equivalent. It's an elementary submodel.